# Add User to Group without notifications

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

With the code below you can Users to a Group. Is there any way to disable notifications? I don't want this to trigger an email to the users added.

```
var user1 = client.Users["myuser@xx.dk"]
  .Request()
  .GetAsync()
  .Result;               

client      
  .Groups[groupId]
  .Owners
  .References
  .Request()
  .AddAsync(user1)
  .Wait();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the .net client for the Microsoft Graph. The request you're referring to is calling the [Add Group Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint. This endpoint doesn't have any other requests parameters.

So the answer is No, you can't. At least not by sending a different request.

There is also a [Uservoice request](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/286611-office-365-groups/suggestions/13121412-disable-email-notifiations-when-assiging-to-group) to enable admins to disable the email notifications when you're added to a group.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is possible with other API or directly via REST?

Comment: No their isn't yet, but you might want to express your need for it on the uservoice

Comment: @ThomasSegato it is nice that if you got the correct answer, that you accept the answer.

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Sorry. And thanks for your help appreciated.